Use WP-CLI to setup Plugins like Wordfence/ LitespeedCache / WoodySnippets
I'm trying to write a shell script that does a default setup for my wordpress websites. However I cannot find a solution to automate loading the settings into these plugins by shell command or php script.
Does anyone have a solution so I don't have to manually setup/ update about 20 wordpress pages with the settings file by hand? I am happy with every solution as long as it shortens the process.
(Installing and activating the plugins isn't an issue.)

This is a question for the developers of  the plugins. And, you may be able to reverse-engineer the option settings for the plugins in question and then use wp option add to set them from the command line.

You can try the below code, it fixes the issue for the wordfence settings when being run in the wp-site folder.
<?php
    // Check if the Wordfence class and method exist
    if (class_exists('wordfence') && method_exists('wordfence', 'importSettings')) {
    // Provide the token for importing settings
    $token = file_get_contents('/Websites/wordpress-setup/wordfence-token.txt');
    if ($token) {
        $result = wordfence::importSettings($token);
        if ($result) {
            echo "Wordfence settings imported successfully.\n";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to import Wordfence settings.\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Wordfence settings token not found or could not be read.\n";
    }
    } else {
       echo "Wordfence importSettings method not available.\n";
       exit(1);
    }

